# Significato di "amore di parte"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Quel fastidioso senso di promiscuità ogni volta, anche poco fa, nell’autobus. Una specie di vertigine che ti attira verso quel ribollire di corpi di facce segnate dall’usura del vicolo. Basterebbe un solo sguardo di simpatia, dato o ricevuto, una semplice occhiata di riconoscimento, un nulla, per sentirsi fagocitato dal magma umano come un albero dalla lava, distrutto, l’appartenenza a se stesso perduta, risucchiato dalla prevalente unità psicologica, sopraffatto e partecipe di colpe storiche. – I preti e i frati concitavano quelle genti con gli stimoli potenti della religione. Senza **amore di parte**, ma per guadagni e rapine, si giuravano sostenitori del trono. Aniello Totonno Ciccillo, orde ingorde della Santafede elettrizzate dalla promessa del sacco risalivano la penisola.

Ho cercato alla [voce "parte" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parte) e di altri dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il significato della locuzione "amore di parte" che appare in questo brano. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Una ricerca di "amore di parte" su Google dà parecchie occorrenze.

Comment: Credo significhi "senza amore per la propria parte" cioè per il loro ruolo di preti o frati.

Comment: @Hachi:     Quindi, nel contesto del brano, il significato sarebbe un amore che manifesta un’adesione totale e acritica alla monarchia? (il testo afferma che quelle persone non avevano questo tipo di amore, ma "si giuravano sostenitori del trono" per ottenere "guadagni e rapine").

Comment: @Hachi: Forse potresti scrivere una risposta alla domanda basandoti su quello che hai trovato sul De Mauro.

Answer (score 2):

La locuzione “di parte” è  molto comune soprattutto  nell'espressione ***“essere di parte“:***

> non essere obbiettivi, essere prevenuti nell’esprimere  un giudizio in quanto sostenitori di una delle parti in causa. (Hoepli)

L’amore “di parte” di cui si parla nel brano si riferisce alla fedeltà alla monarchia professata da queste persone solo in apparenza che in realtà nasconde il reale interesse per guadagni facili e illeciti a cui questi individui  sono dediti.

Comment: Mi sembrava anche interessante la [definizione della locuzione "di parte" del De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/di-parte).